# How do you check if a place in a list is ascii

Tags: python, list, ascii

Ive been looking for a way to do this and ive only found ways to do it with strings i was wondering if it can be done with lists to.

```
#----------------------------
#flesch reading score program
#----------------------------

#----getting file to read----
myfile = open('project2test.txt')
txt = myfile.read()
words = txt.split()
txt = list(txt)
txt.append(' ')

#----global variables----
numWords, numberOfWords, numSentences, numSyllables = 0,0,0,0

punctuation = '.?;:!'
extendedPunctuation = '.?;:!,/<>]}\|)(*&^%$#@'
abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
syllables = 'aeiouAEIOU'
numbers = '1234567890'

#----counting functions----
def sentenceEnd(i,numSentences):
    if txt[i] in punctuation:
        numSentences += 1
    return numSentences

def wordEnd(i,numWords):
    if txt[i] in abc:
        if txt[i+1] == ' ' or txt[i+1] == '\n':
            numWords += 1
        if txt[i+1] in extendedPunctuation:
            numWords += 1
        if txt[i+1] in numbers:
            numWords += 1
    return numWords

def syllableEnd(i,numSyllables):
    if txt[i] in syllables:
        if txt[i+1] not in syllables:
            numSyllables += 1
    return numSyllables

#----main loop----
for i in range(len(txt)):
    numWords = wordEnd(i, numWords)
    numSentences = sentenceEnd(i,numSentences)
    numSyllables = syllableEnd(i,numSyllables)

for word in words:
    numberOfWords += 1


flesh = 206.835 - 1.015 * (numberOfWords/numSentences) - 84.6 * ((numSyllables)/numberOfWords)
print("The flesch redability of your document is: ", flesh) 
print(numSyllables, ' ', numSentences, ' ' , numWords, ' ', numberOfWords)
```

right now i have to define everything.
i bassically want to know if in stead of sat puntuation =, abs = ... list[i].ascii == true

Comment: by place do you mean the list index contains a non-ascii? or?

Comment: What have you tried, and in what way didn't it work? As far as I can see, if you replaced `abc` with a list of single-character strings, it would still work.

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation of what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: yes i mean list index.  I have a file that im reading through and im counting words and sentences and syllables.  for words i want it to recognize a letter then if the next index is not a letter then numWords += 1.  so basically im wondering if instead of making all these strings if i can just do somthing like.                                  
if txt[i+1].ascii and txt[.i+1] not in abc
     numWords += 1

Comment: I wouldn't do that that way at all (regular expressions with the `\w` character class will work better) but if you do want to use that approach, use the builtin `string.letters` in place of your `abc`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.letters There are similar constants for digits and punctuation.

Comment: Is there a way to ceck list.letters?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `if txt[i+1] in string.letters:` will work fine. A string is a kind of list.

Comment: You should be using regex's to do this...

Comment: sorry in prety new to programing but for string.letters you still have to define the string i was wondering if there is a built in database for all ascii values that i can call on

Comment: You don't have to define anything special to use `string.letters`, just import it. `import string` or `from string import letters`.

Answer (score 1):

```
punctuations = [' ',',']
original_string = "Hello,World! How Clean is Python!"

words = []
words.append(original_string)

for x in punctuations:
    temp = []
    for word in words:
        temp += word.split(x)
    words = temp
```

This should work.